# Grouping not working properly in AdvancedDataGrid when using footer?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I have a AdvancedDataGrid with price as one column .i want to display the price total at the bottom of Grid. It worked fine without grouping but when i use grouping it is not working I could not understand why 
the error is:
         "Multiple initializers for property 'dataProvider'. (note: 'dataProvider' is the default property of 'mx.controls.AdvancedDataGrid')."

and my code is :

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
xmlns:local="*" 
width = "100%" viewSourceURL="srcview/index.html" xmlns:adg="com.forestandthetrees.controls.adgFooter.*"> 

<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="myADG1"
                         variableRowHeight="true">        
        <mx:dataProvider>
            <mx:GroupingCollection id="gc" source="{dp}">
                <mx:Grouping label="Sno">
                    <mx:GroupingField name="category"/>
                </mx:Grouping>
            </mx:GroupingCollection>
        </mx:dataProvider>
    <adg:FooterAdvancedDataGrid id="dg4" 
                                paddingTop="0" horizontalScrollPolicy="auto"
                                paddingBottom="0" verticalAlign="middle" width="100%" 
                                lockedColumnCount="1"   >


        <adg:columns>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Sno" dataField="Sno" />

                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="category" dataField="category" />


                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="ProductName" dataField="productName"  />
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Description" dataField="description"  />
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="AvailableStock" dataField="availableStock"  />
            <adg:FooterAdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="pricePerItem" dataField="pricePerItem" >
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn labelFunction="averageFunctionADG" 
                                           dataField="pricePerItem"
                                           />
            </adg:FooterAdvancedDataGridColumn>
        </adg:columns> 
    </adg:FooterAdvancedDataGrid>
    </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

and dataprovider is :

```
private var dp:Array = [
{Sno:"1",category:"biscuits", productName:"50-50", 
    description:"salt", availableStock:12,pricePerItem:12}, 
{Sno:"2",category:"biscuits", productName:"cream", 
    description:"cream", availableStock:12,pricePerItem:12}, 
{Sno:"3",category:"choclates", productName:"5star", 
    description:"choclateflavour", availableStock:12,pricePerItem:12}, 
{Sno:"4",category:"choclates", productName:"kitkat", 
    description:"pineappleflavour", availableStock:12,pricePerItem:12}, 
{Sno:"5",category:"sweets", productName:"sompapad", 
    description:"asd", availableStock:12,pricePerItem:12},
{Sno:"6",category:"sweets", productName:"laddu", 
    description:"", availableStock:12,pricePerItem:12}, 
{Sno:"7",category:"chips", productName:"lays", 
    description:"salt", availableStock:12,pricePerItem:12}, 
{Sno:"8",category:"chips", productName:"kurkure", 
    description:"salt", availableStock:12,pricePerItem:12}];
```